# Array - How do I access value at specified key, without using $array['key'] method?

Tags: php

For example:

```
$fruits = array(
    1 => 'apples',
    2 => 'lemons',
    3 => 'bananas'
);
```

Is there a function to output `lemons`, without using `$fruits[2]`?

Comment: @codemonkey613: Why would you not want to use $fruits[2]? That is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use next(), current(), prev(), end() set of functions. You could use a foreach on the array. You could use the list($var,$var1,$var2...) = $arr construct. Be more specific as to what you're trying to do.

EDIT:

```
If you're looking for a way to echo it in text use 
$foo='LEMON: '.$fruits[2].' =)';
OR
$foo=:LEMON: {$fruits[2]} =)";

foreach($fruits as $k => $v) if ($k===2) echo $v;

list($f1,$f2,$f3) = $fruits;
echo $f2;

next($fruits);
echo next($fruits);

array_shift($fruits);
echo $array_shift($fruits);
```

Comment: There isn't, but you can make one if you use it often. function getValueIndex($output,$key){  return $output[$key]; } ... so then getValueIndex($class->returnsAnArray(),1);

Answer (score 1):

[`array_shift()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php):

```
echo array_shift($fruits);
```

But it works only with the first element in the array of course ;)